# Is it possible to download a file with PHP CLI on the SSH client (like ZOC or putty) with zssh?

Tags: php, ssh

Example of the wanted feature :

> $file='test.csv'; echo 'Download :'."\n".'sz test.csv';

It print the command to copy paste to download the file.
Trying to auto download the file (with the ssh client dialog to confirm), I tried to exec it with php :

> system('sz test.csv');

or

> echo shell_exec('sz test.csv');

it doesn't work with ZOC terminal on Windows, the script is blocked, can't do CTRL+C to exit
Have to copy/paste "sz test.csv"

with :

> passthru('sz test.csv');

It "work half" I get the start of CSV but after I have this error : [image: sz bug with passthru]

I think I need to change something like GC/header but I don't know what to do.

Is it possible to download a file directly in the PHP script ?